# How to fix a bug in my homework solution in C++?

Tags: c++

I need to write a program which reads the statistics of n League A football teams and prints the teams name which fall in League B.

> A team falls in League B, if it has less than k points after having played m weeks where m is between 1 and 150. Each team gets three points for a win, one point for draw and zero points when lost.
>
> Input Specification: In the first line, you will be given the number of teams 0 < n ≤ 500 and the points 0 < k ≤ 300 needed to stay in league A. Then in the following n lines, there will be the team name and its results. Semicolon indicates the end of input series.
>
> Number 2 represents win, number one represents draw and number zero represents loss.
>
> Output specification:
>
> ```
> Sample Input I
> 4 19
> Team_A 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 2 1 0 ;
>
> Team_B 0 1 0 2 2 1 1 0 1 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 2 ;
>
> Team_C 0 0 1 0 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 2 1 2 ;
>
> Team_D 0 1 0 1 2 1 2 1 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 ;
>
> Sample Output I
>
> Team_A 16
>
> Team_B 18
> ```

This is the code I came up with, but the output is wrong and I don't know why,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
 {
  int n,points,sum=0,i,value;
  char name[15];
  char p;
  scanf("%d %d",&n,&points);
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
    scanf("%s",&name);

   do
  {

    scanf("%c ",&p);
    if(p!=';')
    {
        value=p-48;
        sum=sum+value;
    }


   }while(p!=';');

    if(sum<=points)
      printf("%s %d",name,sum);
    }
    return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Please correct your title and indentation.

Comment: Output Specification: Show the team names and their points which fall to League B.

Comment: Then define precisely what outputs you expect, what outputs you got instead, and what you think the problem might be. Make it so that this question can benefit others in the future, not just you. This is a Q&A, not a helpdesk!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: The `scanf` function is evil.  Prefer to use `cin` or if you must, `fscanf(stdin`.

Comment: Prefer to use character literals, such as '0', rather than the ASCII decimal number 48.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of C-style character arrays.  Arrays have overrun potential.

Comment: How exactly is your output wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might look for problems by stuffing the program with output statements.
If you add after `scanf("%c ",&p);` an output statement to show the value of `p`, you will find that the first value for p is a space character, which spoils your calculation.
In the same way, if you trace the value of `value`, you will find that you forgot to initialize this variable to zero for each team.